# Why do I get 'CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder not found' error?

Tags: c#, xamarin, globalization

Okay, this is a strange one.

I'm trying to create a custom culture in Xamarin using:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

var x = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder();
```

But I get the nasty red Resharper error with no options.

The type or namespace name 'CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Globalization'

What's going on, am I missing something? Can't find any help on google...

Comment: What kind of project is it?  Android, iOS, PCL, etc?

Comment: @jason project is for android platform

Comment: Error CS0103: The name `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)

Comment: Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)

Comment: @jason these are the errors

Comment: @Jason is there any hope?

Comment: I'm not a globalization expert - my best guess is that these classes aren't implemented in Xamarin because the underlying platforms (iOS and Android) don't support "custom" cultures, just predefined ones.

Comment: @Jason tnx, would you mind mention somebody who is expert in globalization or some related section? it's my last hope to add persian calendar to my app. otherwise is should rewrite all app in native :|

Comment: report is as a bug at bugzilla.xamarin.com and see what they say